# Load only one appender instead of all

Tags: c#, file, logging, console, log4net

I'm currently working on a console C# app and I have to log two type of data :

- All steps of the app in general (AppLog)
- All information that I get from a service (MachineLog)

MachineLog needs 2 propeties, but when I start the app I do not define them I have some work to do before. But I need to log from start whith AppLog so at le beginning I use :

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

And it create me the C:\DNC\Suivi\Logs.txt but also C:\DNC\Suivi\(null)\(null)-logs.txt

**Is there any way to only load/configure AppLog and later MachineLog ?**

I tried to add parameters to Configure() and all failed.

My App.config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="AppLog" />
    </root>
    <logger name="Machine" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MachineLog" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="AppLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\DNC\Suivi\Logs.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="MachineLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\DNC\Suivi\%property{Machine}\%property{ID}-logs.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current configuration, you can't do it. As you have seen, log4net will create the log files when `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` is called.

In order to this, you will have to do at least some work programmatically, once you know where the file will be - it's quite easy to [set the file name at runtime](http://geekswithblogs.net/wpeck/archive/2009/10/08/setting-log4net-fileappender.file-at-runtime.aspx) so you can have a placeholder file name in the config, then set the correct name at runtime when the values are known. This does mean that the empty placeholder file will exist - the only way around that would be to [create the whole appender at runtime](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200602.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C769745@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E).